# Basic ldif to setup user and group

Tags: ldap, ldif

I've installed `Tivoli Directory Server v6.3` and will be using it as a user registry for `Websphere Portal` and `Websphere Commerce` for `SSO` purposes.

I'm looking to create a basic user entry in `LDAP` but cant quite get the structure of the `.ldif` right, can anyone help me?

This is how I've defined the `suffix` in `LDAP`: `dc=company,dc=com`

And this is my `ldif` ..

```
dn: dc=company,dc=com
uid: cn=users
cn: cn=groups
uid=wpsadmin,cn=users,dc=company,dc=com
cn=wpsadmins,cn=groups,dc=company,dc=com
```

But this is the error I get when trying to import:

```
The input file contains incorrect data at line 4
The input file contains incorrect data at line 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the help you need.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lwm/v1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.lwm.doc_1.0/inst_tds_modldif.html

-jim